# Which type of date format it is?

Tags: php, date

Currently I am implementing one of API.Which returns date as 1389914586 .I don't know which type of date format it is? Whether it is offset format or any other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the number of seconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970, UTC.

You can see what it is displaying by using PHP's date format.

```
<?php

print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1389914586);
```

That will output:

```
2014-01-16 16:23:06
```

Comment: Why force a string to integer conversion when you could just use `1389914586` as an integer? It's within `INT` bounds.

Comment: True.  I will remove the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), calculated as the number of seconds from Thursday, 1 January 1970.